# Cannot npm install ramme with source code

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I try an application unofficial desktop for Instagram, it's called [Ramme](https://github.com/ifedapoolarewaju/igdm).

I followed the instruction when I call npm install

```
> electron@2.0.2 postinstall /home/praz/igdm-master/node_modules/electron
> node install.js

/home/praz/igdm-master/node_modules/electron/install.js:47
  throw err
  ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/praz/igdm-master/node_modules/electron/electron-tmp-download-4691-1533027792561'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 7zip-bin-win@2.2.0 (node_modules/7zip-bin-win):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 7zip-bin-win@2.2.0: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 7zip-bin-mac@1.0.1 (node_modules/7zip-bin-mac):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 7zip-bin-mac@1.0.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! electron@2.0.2 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@2.0.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/praz/.npm/_logs/2018-07-31T09_03_16_012Z-debug.log
```

I get this error log.
I don't know how to get electron on my node modules?

Sorry about my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of issuing,

```
npm install
```

Can you please try executing the following?

```
npm install --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it's work to me sir, before i try it, i called "sudo rm -rf node_modules && sudo npm cache clean --force", and after "sudo npm i" i can get "sudo npm start" Sir. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For windows: use admin command prompt for npm install

For Linux:  use sudo

Try this  if above does not work:

```
sudo npm install electron --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

See this [issue on github](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17268)

Comment: it's i used sudo, sir. my problem i cannot get electron npm when i call npm install?

Comment: check permission on /home/praz/igdm-master dir

Comment: as "drwx - - - - - -" sir

Comment: i try it sir, it's saved on my /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ ,and i try again npm install, i get same error log, sir

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it this way

```
echo "yourRootPasswordHere" | npm install
```

You are this way trying to run yourr node modules installations process giving the installation process the ability to read the root password and perform root actions. Your process is failing because it cant perform a `mkdir`command